# upload file size limit in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In version 2.1.0, spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size property failed to bind org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize.

```
Property : spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize= 50Mb
```

Exception

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size' to org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize:

Property: spring.servlet.multipart.maxfilesize
Value: 50Mb
Origin: "spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize" from property source "bootstrapProperties"
Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to @org.springframework.boot.convert.DataSizeUnit org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Comment: `MB` with a capital 'B'.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.java here you can see that "B" is indeed capital

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898563/michael) & [Stahorszki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8527109/l%C3%A1szl%C3%B3-stahorszki) mentioned

> **"B"**

must be capital

```
Property : spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize= 50MB
```

In Yaml

```
spring:    
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: ${MAX_FILE_SIZE:8MB}
      max-request-size: ${MAX_REQUEST_SIZE:8MB}
```

Comment: Mine had \r at the and Using export I was getting the same Error.

Answer (score 0):

Today I have repeated this error, althought I set "MB" with capital "B":

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size' to org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize:

    Property: spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size
    Value: 300MB 
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:27:40
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
```

If I comment out this options application wouldn't start anyway - there are some errors in the spring context.
So I think it is a wrong error message then context cannot be created + multipart options are given.

Comment: I had a space AFTER 300MB and it was causing it to fail.   Would be nice if binding would remove white spaces automatically and ignore the case comparison on mb or kb.....

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had redundant whitespace at the end of size (after MB, KB). To fix this, I deleted the space.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space as well after 50MB, I faced the same error but due to space after value attribute

[image]